# Java BigDecmal change negative value to positive

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bigdecimal

A third-party service sends a *negative value* to the **BigDecimal** field in my service.
I need to make it *positive*.

I re-read tons of information on BigDecimal in Spring, but couldn't find how to fix this. I don’t know if this can be done with the help of annotation that will automatically change the sign from negative to positive, or do I need to manually change the sign?

For example, my DTO:

```
private BigDecimal priceValue;
```

The value **-14.50** always comes to me, and I want the result to be **14.50** with a "+" sign.

I read in the documentation that *@Positive* can be used - but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: You want this why? Possibly the way it was sent was already correct from the accounting point of view? And have you considered consulting the documentation?

Comment: `@Positive` is one of the validation annotations. It isn't meant to change value.

Comment: if you are using spring you can try custom annotation for this functionality. Also you can check BigDecimal negate() method if your value is always negative

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would say absolute value is your friend here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#abs()

just keep in mind that BigDecimal objects are immutable...

```
public foo() 
{ 
    BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal("-14.51"); 
    System.out.println("Absolute value is " + num.abs()); 
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to use public BigDecimal abs() method ?

Comment: yes, I mean to use it and to be aware that the result is actually in the returned value and is not affecting the instance itself... :)